# Should we get rid of the user-experience tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-blacklist-request

Following on from the [Should we get rid of the User-Interaction tag?](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1431/should-we-get-rid-of-the-user-interaction-tag) question last year, it's now come to my attention that we have currently 95 questions tagged with [user-experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-experience).

As someone in the Graphic Design chatroom pointed out:

> why do you guys have [user-experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-experience) ?
>   seems like every question could be tagged that :D

And I think I agree. So; do we really need this tag? Does it serve a purpose that means we can't get rid of it without compromising something or other? Is the name of the site not clue enough that *every* question will be related to User Experience in some way or another?

If enough people agree then we can request they tag be blacklisted so that users can no longer select it as a tag for their question. But if we have good reason to keep it around then we'll do so (and just get a bit more stringent with tag tidying up).

Comment: I could swear we killed this very tag a while ago. May be thinking of user interaction. Either way, kill it

Comment: @BenBrocka yeah, I thought we had too. I guess not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This tag has been removed and made *intrinsic* (same as a blacklist, but won't block inbound migrations) - it's now in the same class as [user-interface](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-interface), which should give you a clue as to why it wasn't *already* blacklisted.

10 questions had *no other tags* - [please retag them appropriately](https://ux.stackexchange.com/tags/untagged).

Comment: Ooh great! The thought of having to go through 90+ questions manually removing it was giving me palpations.

Comment: @JonW.  I think the word you mean is "palpitations" (which means a fluttering of the heart) not "palpations" (which means examinations by touching).

Answer (score 7):

Given that this whole site is about user experience, the [user-experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-experience) tag is redundant. It's a needless wart. Let's prevent its use.